# javascript - concat a string to a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following in a vue.js script:

```
<v-tab v-for="type in searchTypes" :id="type.value" :key="type.value" @click="getSelectValue(type.value)">
```

I want to append the id of "type.value" with a fixed string "_tab"

I have tried various ways without getting it to work. Any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript expressions to contat the string like this:

```
<v-tab v-for="type in searchTypes" :id="type.value + '_tab'" :key="type.value" @click="getSelectValue(type.value)">
```

I hope this can help you here is the source:

[Using JavaScript Expressions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal syntax to do that. I'm a React guy, but I think this will work. Hopefully I understood the question correctly.

```
<v-tab v-for="type in searchTypes" :id="`_tab${type.value}`" :key="type.value" @click="getSelectValue(type.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string interpolation:

```
<v-tab v-for="type in searchTypes" :id="`${type.value}_tab`" :key="type.value" @click="getSelectValue(type.value)">
```